# My Description has Shortened

Tags: mysql

Hello all i have created a form that simply uploads a description of an item to the database, but when i then echo that contents, its shortened the description my description was 500 words and i only see 100

```
<?php

        include('config.inc');
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = $con;     

        // Gather all required data

        $description    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `paid_reports` (

               `description`, 

            )
            VALUES (

               '{$description}',

            )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);


    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}
```

MySql: Table

```
0   description tinyblob    0   0   0
```

any ideas?

please don't give me abuse I came here for help I'm asking for help. :)

Comment: What is the table definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TINYBLOB` [holds a maximum of 255 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html). That's likely your problem. Change it to `BLOB` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from `tinyblob` to `text` and you will be fine.